# error al exportar archivo de excel en asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buen día espero que me puedan ayudar con este detalle ya que tengo mucho tiempo y nada mas no doy con la solución

tengo una aplicación hecha en C# .NET  la aplicación funciona perfectamente en mi maquina local , consiste en exportar un archivo de excel  para actualizar datos a una tabla de de BD (aqui todo bien el codigo funciona)

el detalle es que al momento de probar la aplicación ya una vez estando en el servidor de producción, me muestra un error que es el siguiente al dar clic en el botón de exportar

error : **no error message available, result code:E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005)**.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el servidor donde monto mi aplicación es un windows server 2016 64 bits  y es donde me sale ese error , cabe mencionar que desde que se migro el server si funcionaba en un windows server 2008 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

Parece que la aplicación no tiene permisos. 
Si tu publicación es en un servidor IIS, Asegurate que el usuario **IIS_IUSRS** tenga  permisos de leer y/o escribir en la carpeta destino.

¿Cómo dar permisos en IIS? por ejemplo: si quisieras escribir el archivo en C:\New Folder. Sigue estos pasos:

- Sobre la carpeta Clic derecho y propiedades
- Pestaña de seguridad
- Clic en Editar
- Clic en Agregar
- Escribe IIS_IUSRS
- Clic en comprobar nombres
- Clic en Aceptar
- Selecciona las casillas de permisos deseados
- Aceptar

Comment: muchas gracias Eliezer por el apoyo ya realice las indicaciones que me diste , pero aun así me sigue saliendo ese mismo error , que mas me podría estar faltando muchas gracias por el apoyo

Comment: mira este enlace, espero te pueda servir.
[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/f91144ff-d8ca-4b2f-b739-f7c29447209d/error-al-publicar-sitio-web-en-aspnet-iis?forum=netfxwebes]